# Clojure: a function that search for a val in a nested hashmap and returns the sequence of keys in which the val is contained

Tags: clojure

Say we have a collection containing a nested data structure:

```
(def coll
  {:a "aa"
   :b {:d "dd"
       :e {:f {:h "hh"
               :i "ii"}
           :g "gg"}}
   :c "cc"})
```

I would like to create a function that search for a val anywhere in the nested structure and returns the sequence of keys in which the val is contained

```
(search-parents "gg" coll) ; or (search-parents coll "gg")
;> [:b :e :g]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no built-in function that does this. It seems like you're essentially looking for an inverse of `clojure.core/get-in`. I thinking `clojure.walk` might be useful here, but I don't think this is a very good fit.

However, it's pretty straightforward to code up a recursive function to do the search and only return matching keys:

```
(defn find-in [coll x]
  (some
    (fn [[k v]]
      (cond (= v x) [k]
            (map? v) (if-let [r (find-in v x)]
                       (into [k] r))))
    coll))
```

Comment: I thought clojure.walk too, but this needs a context, zippers could maybe work

Comment: It seems this solution is problematic. I get [:b :e :f] returning from (find-in coll "gg"). It appears to stem from (vec nil) returning []. A slight alteration seems to work: (defn find-in [coll x] (some (fn [[k v] (cond (= v x) [k] (map? v) (if-let [r (find-in v x)] (into [k] r)))) coll))

Comment: Nice guys! just add up a closing square bracket to [[k v]] and it works fine! Maybe DaoWen you want to update your answer so I mark your answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: @OmriBernstein - Thanks for catching that! Originally I was returning a list—I didn't think about `vec` breaking the falsiness for `nil`. My solution would have been to update the recursive call to `(if-let [r (seq (find-in v x))]`, which would give me `nil` like I wanted. However, I think I like your solution better!. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had a need to expand it to cover also a vector of maps:

```
(defn find-in [coll x]
  (some
    (fn [[k v]]
      (cond (= v x) [k]
            (map? v) (if-let [r (find-in v x)]
                       (into [k] r))
            (vector? v) (let [v1 (mapv #(find-in % x) v)]
                          (if-let [r (some #(when % %) v1)]
                            (let  [i (.indexOf v1 r)]
                              (into (into [k] [i]) r))
                              ))))
         coll))
```