# ClojureScript search in nested map and vector

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, edn

I have an edn in which I have nested maps. I found one very good example for this [Clojure: a function that search for a val in a nested hashmap and returns the sequence of keys in which the val is contained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731373/clojure-a-function-that-search-for-a-val-in-a-nested-hashmap-and-returns-the-se#)

```
(def coll
  {:a "aa"
   :b {:d "dd"
       :e {:f {:h "hh"
               :i "ii"}
           :g "hh"}}
   :c "cc"})
```

With this answer

```
(defn find-in [coll x]
    (some
(fn [[k v]]
  (cond (= v x) [k]
        (map? v) (if-let [r (find-in v x)]
                   (into [k] r))))
coll))
```

My problem is that because of `some` I can't get a path for every result, only for the first logical truth. I tried `map` an `keep` but they break the recursion. How could I make this code to give back path to all of its results, not only the first one? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you need the flexibility of a Ring Server (https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring - but there are others as well)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, what does it have to do with server-side? It's a clojurescript frontend app, the edn is on frontend, I just need a search function for it. Till now I managed to do something like this (defn                               find-in [coll x] (some (fn [[k v]] (print k) (cond 
            (not (map? v)) (if (s/includes? (s/lower-case (str v)) (s/lower-case x))[k] nil) (map? v) (if-let [r (seq (find-in v x))]
                      
                    (into [k] r))
                     
                       ))
    coll))

Comment: Hi Paul, please edit your question and add the code you come up with in the question, in the comment section is barely readable. Also clarify where you are having difficulties, now is not very clear. Be concise and clear, some info on how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Marcs, you are totally right, I tried to simplify it to the very core of my problem. Hope it is better this time.

Comment: Exhaustive search is OK once in a while, but if you're doing a lot of this, you should reconsider your data structures or build indices.  See Datascript for a better approach: https://github.com/tonsky/datascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a helper function to turn a nested map into a flat map with fully qualified keys.  Then find-in can just filter on the value and returns the matched keys.

```
(defn flatten-map [path m]
  (if (map? m)
    (mapcat (fn [[k v]] (flatten-map (conj path k) v)) m)
    [[path m]]))

(defn find-in [coll x]
  (->> (flatten-map [] coll)
       (filter (fn [[_ v]] (= v x)))
       (map first)))
```

With your sample:

```
(find-in coll "hh")
=>
([:b :e :f :h] [:b :e :g])
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` gives all of the results, where `some` will only give you the first result, or `nil` if there aren't any. Oftentimes the same problem can be solved by filtering then taking the first, rather than using `some`.

Comment: I tried filter, it doesn't work as expected. Returns with nil too, so it would make paths like [:a :b nil]. Could you show me how?

Comment: Are you trying to write a function that given `coll` and "hh" will return `[:b :e :f :h]`?

Comment: Yes but all paths, not only the first. So given a coll and "hh" will return [[:b :e :f :h] [:b :e :g]] if these paths would have the value of "hh".

Comment: There are libraries that 'walk the tree', so you don't have to work out the recursion yourself. For instance `clojure.walk`, `clojure.zip` and `specter`. But I think your question is really how to implement this tree walking.

Comment: Yes, the question would be how. Can anybody modify this snippet to work as I want it to work, or some other algorithm with this result?